# After the launcher autohides, windows do not resize top full screen in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, launcher, themes, mac, autohide

After the launcher auto hides the windows do not resize itself to full screen .Instead a rectangular space is left on left side of  Ubuntu 14.04.

Like [this](http://postimg.org/image/8dzf7hwtp/)

How can I fix it so the window resizes to full screen when the launcher auto-hides?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please upload a screenshot to imgur.com and provide a link so that we can see what you see. Thank you!

Comment: here is snapshot http://postimg.org/image/8dzf7hwtp/

Comment: and i have applied mac os theme over ubuntu earliar it was working fine but once i disabled the unity via compiz config setting manager and then i restarted it using  commands on terminal then this issue come up .the reason i turned of unity was that , i was trying to get rid of unity launcher so that i can use docky   exclusively ..thanks for any help!

Comment: here is snapshot http://postimg.org/image/8dzf7hwtp/  you can see a rectangular dark area on left because the window has not resized it to full

Comment: okay issue was with docky. i turned docky off the the window took my whole screen

Comment: I'm glad you got it solved! Please write up your solution as an answer so others who have your issue can benefit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem. It was a second empty Docky panel. To fix this: open Docky 'Preferences' then select empty space (while you have some window in fullscreen mode) and then click 'Remove Panel'. Empty space should disappear.